# Serving content over HTTPS

Tags: graphdb

Can GraphDB Free be configured in any way to allow content to be served over HTTPS?

I'm creating a simple front-end web application using Angular2 that makes HTTP requests to the GraphDB SPARQL endpoint.

I'm using Windows IIS and the server has been setup not to trust any content this is not served over HTTPS.

Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

According the instructions in GraphDB's configuration file `$GDB_HOME/conf/graphdb.properties`, to enable HTTPS uncomment the following lines:

```
# Enable SSL (uncomment to enable)
graphdb.connector.SSLEnabled = true
graphdb.connector.scheme = https
graphdb.connector.secure = true

# GraphDB uses the Java implementation of SSL, which requires a configured key in the Java keystore.
# To setup keystore uncomment the following properties and set keystorePass and keyPass to the actual values.

graphdb.connector.keyFile = <path to the keystore file if different from ${graphdb.home}/keystore>
graphdb.connector.keystorePass = <secret>
graphdb.connector.keyAlias = graphdb
graphdb.connector.keyPass = <secret>
```

If you use a self-signed certificate add it to the keystore with:

```
keytool -genkey -alias graphdb -keyalg RSA
```

If you have a third-party trusted OpenSSL certificate, you would need to convert it to PKCS12 key and then import to the Java keystore with:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass MYPASS -srckeystore mypkcs12.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

For additional information on how to deal with the third party trusted certificates check this excellent link explaining in great details how to convert [import private key and certificate into java keystore](https://coderwall.com/p/3t4xka/import-private-key-and-certificate-into-java-keystore)

**Edited**

To locate the $GDB_HOME directory for the desktop installation, check the [GraphDB documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/quick-start-guide.html#the-graphdb-home-directory).

Comment: I cannot seem to find the graphdb.properties file in my ubuntu system

Comment: It should be under $GDB_HOME/conf/graphdb.properties

Comment: there are differences between desktop and stand-alone server

Comment: To locate the $GDB_HOME path in the desktop installation check the GraphDB documentation http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/quick-start-guide.html#the-graphdb-home-directory